Placeholder item in Swiper slide
We are using SwiperJs for the carousel. There is a placeholder with multiple items and I want to render each item of the placeholder in a SwiperSlide. How can I render? I am trying to achieve it in this way but I can't. I tried using Placeholder render and renderEach. Below code snippet shows the implementation of both
{slidesData && (
          <Swiper
            loop={AutoLoop?.value}
            keyboard={true}
            navigation={true}
            pagination={{ clickable: true }}
            modules={[A11y, Pagination, Navigation, Keyboard]}
          >
            {slidesData.map((component: ComponentRendering | HtmlElementRendering, index) => (
              <SwiperSlide key={index}>
                <Placeholder rendering={rendering} name="jss-carousel-items">
                </Placeholder>
                
              </SwiperSlide>
            ))}

            {/* {rendering && (
            <Placeholder
              name="jss-carousel-items"
              rendering={rendering}
              renderEach={(component: any, index: number) => {
                return (
                  <SwiperSlide key={index} >
                    {component}
                  </SwiperSlide>
                );
              }}
              mobileLayoutOnly={true}
            ></Placeholder>
          )} */}
          </Swiper>
        )}


You will need to create dynamic placeholders for each slide in Sitecore and use it. You can refer below documentations:
https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/solving-placeholder-issues-in-sitecore-xm-cloud-with-nextjs
https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/walkthrough--configure-your-components-to-use-dynamic-placeholders.html
